# What is the escape character for column filters using like in SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I am trying to find an example of a specific exploit in our sql server traces and I want to filter the TextData column for '%' occurring three times:  %%%.

This means that I have to escape the special character %.

One try was to use '\' as an escape char like this: %\%\%\%%

Another try was to specify it as a range: %[%][%][%]%.

In SQL we can specify the escape character to use for the LIKE operator, but is there a way to do it when we filter in SQL Server Profiler?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  
  
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15